# silverlight service reference from wsdl - methods missing

Tags: .net, silverlight, web-services, .net-4.0, service-reference

I'm successfully creating a Service Reference for a silverlight application by pointing to a local wsdl file. The preview pane shows the 6 methods avaialble in this wsdl.

However, the generated proxy seems to have no knowledge of those methods, so I cannot find a way to call them.

Been fighting this for a while, what the heck is going on? I can post additional details here if needed, thanks.

Comment: Ive found that running svcutil on the wsdl directly *does* generate the methods. apparently running the tool inside vs2010 is erroring in some way. weird stuff.